# display dynamic component in angular v10 using dynamic id selector

Tags: angular

I am working with ElementRef, ViewConatinerRef and Renderer2 for modifying DOM.
but now I am trying to add component to DOM with dynamic id selector. How to do this without @viewchild()

app.component.html

```
//<!-- <div #id_1></div> -->

<div [attr.id]= 'dynamicID'></div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
 dynamicID:string = 'id_1';
  // @ViewChild('id_1', { read: ElementRef}) ele;
  
  constructor(private vc:ViewContainerRef, private injector: Injector, private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver, private render:Renderer2) { }
  ngOnInit() {

  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   
    let component = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FirstComponent);
    let componetRef = component.create(this.injector);
    componetRef.instance.data = 'test data';
    let hostView = componetRef.hostView;
   //here how to get that dynamicID (id_1)  and append hostView to that 'dynamicID' div
  }

}
```

Thank you

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve in the DOM ? Angular advocates against directly manipulating the DOM and prefers UI changes based on variable changes in the code. Is it possible to use that approach to achieve the same result ?

Comment: I am new to angular. I don't know which way is best. In my project placeholders(dynamic divs) are dynamic. Those place holders are coming from the database and  based on the placeholder we can attached the component to the DOM. for example placeholders like <div id="div_1"></div><div id='div_2'></div>.

Comment: So you want to populate a list of divs, with the number depending upon the response from the database ?

Comment: yes @DelwynPinto. html content saved in database based on user. Different user contains different html. In that html we configured ids. Based on those ids we can append appropriate component

Comment: @DelwynPinto even I got the same use case. I am working on a task where I insert content dynamically. And then I need to replace some part of the inserted content based on ID only. There is no other way. I am converting markdown to html, then replace tokens inside markdown with angular components. How else do we replace tokens with angular components? Sarvesh's answer is actually completely unblocked me. Kudos Sarvesh.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After lot of searches I got the solution.

app.component.html

```
<div [attr.id]='dynamicID'></div>
```

app.component.ts

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit {
dynamicID: string = 'test';
constructor(
    private eRef: ElementRef,
    private vc: ViewContainerRef,
    private injector: Injector,
    private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver,
    private render: Renderer2,
    private app: ApplicationRef
   ) { }

  ngOnInit() {  }
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    let factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(GridComponent);
    let node = this.render.createElement('div');
    let html = document.querySelector('#' + this.dynamicID).appendChild(node);
    let componetRef = factory.create(this.injector, [],node);
    componetRef.instance.data = 'this is dynamically added component';
    this.app.attachView(componetRef.hostView);
  }
}
```

Comment: You're a true legend man. Looks like people are just using basic angular. They might have never tried this. Thanks for all the help. This solution unblocked a POC that I am researching.

Answer (score -1):

The correct way to do this, would be by using Angular's [ngFor directive](https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt2). It lets you run a for loop over a JSON array / object in the HTML template. Its basic syntax is

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    {(item)}
</div>
```

data will be the variable in which the database response is stored. Modify the content between the  as you need.